# How to write a SQL query to find number of accounts tied to a particular value?

Tags: sql

I want to find the number of companies tied to a specific membership field. This is somewhat complex, as many different companies can belong to the same membership number. Companies are identified by a 6 character string (account number), but in this table they can be either 6 or 8 characters long. I am only interested in accounts that are 6 characters, or 8 characters where the last two characters are 00. To make matters worse, there are many duplicate account numbers in this table -- the field is not unique.

The membership field is numeric, but can also be null. I care only about non-zero, non-null membership numbers. Unfortunately it's random whether or not the user input a null, a zero, or an actual number.

The end result is to display all the membership numbers with a count of how many account numbers belong.

All the information is from the same table. Each row will have an account number and membership number among many other fields.

Think of it like a franchise situation. Let's pretend Burger Joint is our customer, so we have a membership number for them. Then, all the franchisees with different account numbers, use the membership number to do business with us. I'm trying to find out how much REAL business is done with each membership.

I realize this may be a multi-step process. Below is my attempt to try to get back the correct account number types. AQT didn't seem to like it though.

```sql
where (length(account) > 6 and substring(account, (length(account) -2), length(account)) ='00')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Companies are identified by a 6 character string (account number), but in this table they can be either 6 or 8 characters long. I am only interested in accounts that are 6 characters, or 8 characters where the last two characters are 00

```
WHERE (accountnumber LIKE '______' or accountnumber LIKE '______00')
```

> I care only about non-zero, non-null membership numbers

```
AND membershipnumber > 0
```

You don't need to specifically check for null member numbers; requiring the number be greater than 0 excludes nulls implicitly

> The end result is to display all the membership numbers with a count of how many account numbers belong

```
SELECT membershipnumber, COUNT(DISTINCT accountnumber) as count_unique_accs
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY membershipnumber
```

Doesn't matter if accountnumber is duplicated: count distinct only gives the unique occurrences. **If 123456 and 12345600 are the same accountnumber, substring inside the count**

Edit:

By this last sentence I mean:

```
 COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(accountnumber, 1, 6)) --sql server syntax
```

Comment: Can the above be used with Hogan's answer? Both contain pieces that I need to fully answer this puzzle. 

Additionally, is it possible to ensure there are no duplicate strings going from 6 to 8 characters? Meaning, if the first 6 characters are the same, so long as the ending two are 00, it would be considered a duplicate entry and not counted.

Is it also possible to display other output information alongside the count? Could I list the account numbers, and then the account names under the membership and count?

Comment: *Meaning, if the first 6 characters are the same, so long as the ending two are 00, it would be considered a duplicate entry and not counted* - See the last line of my answer; I did wonder if that would be the case hence I mentioned that **If 123456 and 12345600 are the same accountnumber, substring inside the count**

Comment: *Could I list the account numbers, and then the account names under the membership and count?* - no; databases don't work that way. You can list the account names alongside the membership and count and the member/count will be repeated for every account, but it's a considerable undertaking to turn a database query output into the drilldown report style thing you propose, and you wouldn't do it because that's the job of the front end reports package, not the back end DB. (You can make a DB do it but the output isn't very usable)

Comment: *Can the above be used with Hogan's answer?* The advice in my answer is a replacement of Hogan's answer not a supplement to it. All you have to do is take the nuggets of SQLs I've written and put them back together accordingly. As a rule you shouldn't modify table data when you're searching through it because it means indexes can't be used. `LIKE '______00'` will find 6 characters followed by 00, as will `(length(account) = 8 and right(account,2) = '00'))` but is a poor choice because requires twice as many function calls as there are rows in the table and cuts strings up just to compare them

Comment: I appreciate it! I'm really new to all this.

I realized the plug and play nature of your suggestion after I played around with things a bit more. For my task, the count was sufficient. But I was curious if there was a more comprehensive way to do things. It makes sense that it's not so easy to do. I guess I'm still feeling out the limitations of what I can reasonably produce.

Comment: If you're preparing reports at that sort of level you'd typically export the detail and get the front end reports package to do the unique count etc

Answer (score 0):

```
where membership is not null and membership <> 0 and account is not null 
  and (length(account) = 6
  or (length(account) = 8 and right(account,2) = '00'))
```

Comment: `membership is not null and membership <> 0` can be simplified to `membership <> 0`

Comment: true @a_horse_with_no_name -- I could have also used a coalesce statement -- but I wanted to keep it as close to the question to keep it clear for the OP.

Comment: The coalesce() would also be unnecessary - any check for "not null" is unnecessary if you also check for a specific value

Comment: ok I'm not sure what you mean by unnecessary -- the compiler will optimize all of these the same anyway -- you just mean extra characters on the screen?  If so, my point is sometimes style and clarity over-ride the need to write the fewest number of characters